# vscode git changes are stuck as fully expanded

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm having a problem where whenever I make a change in vscode, it is shown fully expanded with the previous change also shown (I realize this description is less than clear, so I've included an image below).  If anyone knows how to fix this I'd appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else confused by this, I figured out the solution.  For some reason my file was open in the working tree. I'm not sure how I did this, but the problem was fixed by closing the file tab, and reopening the file from the explorer